# init-statement in selection statements only available in C++17

Tags: c++

Programando en C++ el código que se puede ver más abajo obtengo, entre otros varios, el error:

```
warning: init-statement in selection statements only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z
     if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream{ "r:\\dummyValues.dat" }; sourceFileStream) {
```

No estoy seguro de entender bien el porqué, pero ¿es un error debido a que no tengo instalado C++17 en mi Linux? De ser así, ¿cómo lo descargo en Ubuntu?

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::regex reFloat{ R"([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)" };

using SVector = std::vector<std::string>;
using SVectorIter = SVector::iterator;

int main() {
    // Open source file and check, if it coud be opened
    if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream{ "r:\\dummyValues.dat" }; sourceFileStream) {

        // Open destination file and check, if it could be opened
        if (std::ofstream finalFileStream("r:\\benchmarks_final.dat"); finalFileStream) {

            // Algorithm start ----------------------------------------------------------
            // Define a string variable and initialize it with the contents of the file
            std::string completeFile(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFileStream), {});

            // Define vector and initialize it with all float values from the file
            SVector values(std::sregex_token_iterator(completeFile.begin(), completeFile.end(), reFloat), {});

            // Iterate over the vector and find the next value equal to first-value
            for (SVectorIter svi{ values.begin() }; (svi = std::find(svi, values.end(), values[0])) != values.end(); ++svi) {

                 // Copy 16 value to the final file
                std::copy_n(svi, std::min(16, std::distance(svi, values.end())), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(finalFileStream, " "));
                finalFileStream << '\n';
            }
            // Algorithm end ----------------------------------------------------------
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open final file\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n";
    }
}
```

La idea es que el archivo dummyValues.dat pase de

```
{1 2 3 4 5 , 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13.3 14.58 15 16} 1000,   2000, {{{1 2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8 9.9 10.10 11.11 12012.3 133.3 14478 ,,, 155.2 16.66 177.23 18.8 } 20000
```

A solo números separados por espacios en blanco y tal que cada vez que aparece un '1' se cambia de línea y se conserven solo los 16 primeros valores de cada tanda iniciada con un '1':

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13.3 14.58 15 16
1 2 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8 9.9 10.10 11.11 12012.3 133.3 14478 155.2 16.66
```

Este sería el resultado que se guardaría en `benchmarks_final.dat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿ Es un error debido a que no tengo instalado C++17 ?

En absoluto.

Es un **aviso** (*warning*) porque C++, en versiones anteriores a C++17, **no soporta** la inicialización de variables dentro de las expresiones en los [`if( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

En versiones de C++ anteriores, los [`if( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) son de la forma

> if( CONDICIÓN ) SENTENCIA

Siendo `CONDICIÓN`:

1. Una expresión convertible a `bool`.
2. Una declaración de una variable, no-formación, inicializada mediante llaves `{ }`.

Por lo tanto, tu código

```
if( std::ifstream sourceFileStream{ "r:\\dummyValues.dat" }; sourceFileStream ) { ...
```

**No se ajusta** a lo esperado por el compilador.

Las soluciones pasan por:

- Usando el `punto 1` anterior y ámbitos anidados:

  ```
  {
    std::ifstream sourceFileStream( "r:\\dummyValues.dat" );
    if( sourceFileStream ) {
      ...
      std::ofstream finalFileStream( "r:\\benchmarks_final.dat" );
      if( finalFileStream ) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Usando el `punto 2` anterior:

  ```
  if( std::ifstream sourceFileStream{ "r:\\dummyValues.dat" } ) {
    ...
    if( std::ofstream finalFileStream{ "r:\\benchmarks_final.dat" } ) {
      ...
  ```

Comment: Se te ha olvidado mencionar que otra solución es añadir `-std=c++17` a los parámetros de compilación.

Comment: En realidad no se me ha olvidado. Simplemente, no la he puesto :-)

Comment: Tanto si se te ha olvidado como si no la has puesto, el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Si te soy franco, tengo la sospecha de que esa es la respuesta que el OP hubiera preferido. Si alguien lo publicara como respuesta, es muy posible que fuera la aceptada.

Comment: Podría poder ser posible.